# Which one is correct: have happened or had happened?

Tags: past-tense, sentence-choice

Which of these sentences is correct?

> 1. So, **which one have happened** yesterday? You went for a walk or stay here?

or

> 2. So **which one had happened**? You went for a walk or stay here?

Or maybe "which one had happen"?

Comment: "So what happened yesterday? Did you go for a walk or stay here?"

Comment: happen is not used like that. Events happen. Activities like go for walk, go fishing do not. ["Did you go for a walk or stay here?" is really the idiomatic question form.]

Answer (score 1):

I would rephrase the first sentence to this:

> "So, what happened yesterday? You went for a walk or did you stay here?"

or

> "So, what did you do yesterday? Did you go for a walk or did you stay?"

Both point out with the help of the second sentence that the expected answer is limited to only two possible answers, the person went for a walk or stayed.

If you're only looking for small adjustments to what you already have I'd rephrase sentence number 2 to this:

> "So what happened? You went for a walk or stayed here?"

Note that sentence number 2 does not specify the day (yesterday) you're referring to in sentence number 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask that:

> So, what happened yesterday? You went for a walk or did you stay here?"

Because we use “did”(simple past tense) when we knew something had happened but wanted more details.